# What happens to a nested if statement in a for-loop if the conditions are not met and there is no else statement?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, nested

This is the code my prof gave on a practice exam. Since the first if statement has no else statement, does it exit the for-loop all together and move onto the next if statement? Then, if the second if-statement evaluates to true I'm assuming it's going to go through the first for-loop again and then the second. Once it starts goes through the second for-loop again does the loop begin at j=1 again or another value?

I'm also a little confused with what happens in the second if statement. Does it mean the value at what the currentMaxIndex is becomes the s[i] value and then the currentMax value?

Thanks!

```
public class Cards {
  public static String[] sortCards(String[] s){ // SELECT SORT
     for (int i = s.length - 1; i >= 1; i--){
         // Find the maximum in the list[0..i]
         String currentMax = s[0];
         int currentMaxIndex = 0;
         for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
             if (cardLessThan(currentMax,s[j])){
                 currentMax = s[j];
                 currentMaxIndex = j;
             }
         }
         // Swap list[i] with s[currentMaxIndex] if necessary;
         if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
             s[currentMaxIndex] = s[i];
             s[i] = currentMax;
          }
     }  
     return s;
    }
 static boolean cardLessThan(String s1, String s2){
     char s1s = s1.charAt(s1.length()-1); //suites
     char s2s = s2.charAt(s2.length()-1);
     if(s1s < s2s)
         return true;
     else if(s1s > s2s)
         return false;
     // Same suite cards - order determined by card number
     String n1 = s1.substring(0,s1.length()-1);
     String n2 = s2.substring(0,s2.length()-1);
     if(n1.equals("A") && !n2.equals("A")) return true;
     if(n1.equals("2") && !n2.equals("A") && !n2.equals("2")) return true;
     …
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: answer is... debug the code and see for your self.

Comment: @aadi53 How helpful... You could write this comment for any question on this site. I don't think that debugityourself.com would be a very popular question and answer site.

Comment: @localhost if you have noticed, he already have the code. all he have to do is just debug it line by line to get his answer. And yes I was trying to help him, for his best interest and to become a good programmer, I would suggest to learn debugging right way ASAP.

Comment: @aadi53 I'm taking this one comp sci class and that's it, never again. I just want to learn this for the final so i don't fail

Comment: @user4343563 I wasn't mean to be rude before. Well if you want to learn programming, one thing you definitely need patience and ambition!! Good Luck for your final!!

Answer (score 0):

If the condition isn't met the loop continues onto the next iteration, and the condition is tested again. That inner loop could also have been written like,

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    if (!cardLessThan(currentMax,s[j])){
        continue;
    }
    currentMax = s[j];
    currentMaxIndex = j;
}
```